# Compare if string starts with symbol @ jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi guys anybody knows how to evaluate y a string starts with symbol "@", i am trying

```
myvar.substring(0,1)==="@"
```

But it gives me error, any idea?

**UPDATE**

I am working with .NET and mvc4, so it recognizes the @ as a symbol for cshtml, i am looking for a way out to compare that symbol

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: it is correct..plz post the error which you are getting.

Comment: Encode the character and then compare..

Comment: keep your JS in a JS file, where it belongs, and you won't have to worry about escaping your templating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
myvar.substring(0,1)==="@"
```

Try

```
myvar.substring(0,1)==="@@"  //use two '@' as shown here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `charCodeAt` to get an integer for the character '@' so you don't need to use '@':

```
myvar.charCodeAt(0) === 64
```